# Typo3 sr_feuser_register e-mail template not working img tag

Tags: html, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

i have to change the default confirmation emial template in sr_feuser_register ext, i'd changed succesfully every markers content but i have to insert an image into the html email and it don't want to work... i tried to replace the marker with te whole i.m.g. tag (img src="....") and i've tried ti replace only the src (img src="marker")... but dosn't work. anybody met this problem already?

Comment: What's not working exactly? is the email being sent at all? Also make sure you send the mail as `HTML` (setting `plugin.tx_srfeuserregister_pi1.email.HTMLMail = 1`). Also take a look at http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-sf_register as sr_feuser_register is not being developed any more..

Comment: i'm overwriting the label from locallang... it dosn't replace the marker.... i've checked to ....email.HTMLMail = 1, it's ok. i tried to replace the special chars (<,",>) with &quot; &lt; etc then he ecos the whole img tag in the mail.

Comment: Check formFields (and maybe requiredFileds) in sr_feuser_register ts *constants*. The field must be listed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable html:

```
plugin.tx_srfeuserregister_pi1.create.fields = module_sys_dmail_html .....

plugin.tx_srfeuserregister_pi1.create.defaultValues.module_sys_dmail_html = 1

and in template file tx_srfeuserregister_pi1_css_tmpl.html
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_CREATE### begin -->
...........
    <!-- ###SUB_INCLUDED_FIELD_module_sys_dmail_html### -->
    <dt>

    </dt>
    <dd>
        <input type="hidden" title="" name="FE[fe_users][module_sys_dmail_html]" value="test">
    </dd>
    <!-- ###SUB_INCLUDED_FIELD_module_sys_dmail_html### -->
.............
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_CREATE### end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexo's answer did not work for me. Instead, I activated Direct Mail and set the dmail-Checkbox in the HTML-Template to hidden.

```
<!-- ###SUB_INCLUDED_FIELD_module_sys_dmail_html### -->
...
<div style="display:none;"><!--TCA_INPUT_module_sys_dmail_html--></div>
...
<!-- ###SUB_INCLUDED_FIELD_module_sys_dmail_html### -->
```

Also, in the Constants you can set

```
plugin.tx_srfeuserregister_pi1.dmailCheckedUponRegistration = 1
```

to make sure the checkbox is checked on default.